# Oracle Database 18C XE Installation completed with Errors

Tags: oracle-database, oracle-12c, windows-10-pro

I am getting the below error while trying to install Oracle Database 18C XE on my local system (Windows 10 Pro).

> **Oracle Database Installation Completed with Errors**
>
> The wizard was interrupted before Oracle Database 18c Express Edition could be completely installed.
>
> Your system has not been modified. To complete installation at another time, please run setup again.
>
> Click Finish to exit the wizard.

I tried removing the environment variable `Oracle_Home` and installed again. Still the installation is rolling back with errors.

How can I resolve this error?

[image: image of error window (see text above)]

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve the problem by running `setup.exe` instead of `Oracle Database 18c Express Edition.msi`

Comment: Worked for me as well. Seems that setup.exe calls the .msi file. I expected the opposite.

Comment: setup.exe runs some prerequisite setups before calling the .msi file. Maybe that's where problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. What I did is uninstall old oracle from Control Panel - Programs - uninstal. After that I close all programs and install oracle again.

Comment: You can also remove programs by typing appwiz.cpl in the run window ( windows button + r )

Answer (score 0):

After doing a fair bit of googling on this I concluded there are any number of problems that can cause this. Bottom line is the installer is a bit lame.
For me, it resolved by me first uninstalling my Java SE and then running the Oracle XE Installer again.
Given that this seems pretty fragile it might be worth running it in a VM.

Answer (score -1):

remove any java/jre path specified in the environment variable .Also first delete the previously created forder( certain folder was created delete the whole path from ..\product ) when earlier you tried to install .

Answer (score -1):

Create new local user in Windows and then install there. It worked for me.